# Missing refiners on the left of my search result page in my custom masterpage

Tags: search-results, custom-masterpage, refiner

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have installed some design package. And now I am using this new custom masterpage. It is beautifule, but I am missing the refiners area on the left of my search result page. I think it is some user control I am missing in my custom masterpage. Does someone know which user control it is?

When I use the out of the box masterpage I see the refiners again.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. Took a copy of oslo didn't change a comma and it turned out the same - no refinementpanel. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your master page design did not account for the PlaceHolderLeftNavBar in the default Search Result page layout. If you have a page layout that is similar you can just recreate the page and add the desired web part.